# Overlay Plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot 2 different data on the same plot which has the same x and y range. [Click here to see the results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrWKg.png). As you can see, the one on the left has a space on 2004. I need to place the second data point (in color blue) there. However,the one on the right is the result.  Can someone help me solve this problem?

This is my current code:

```
plot1 <- c(64123456,75123456....,99417287) #total of 29 values
plot2 <- c(80824322)

plot(plot1, col="red",pch=16,xlab = "Year", ylab = "Population",main = "Population of XXX from 1990 to 2020",yaxt="n",xaxt="n",las=2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(plot2, col="blue",pch=17,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
```

UPDATE:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E81al.png) is the result when I used `points(plot2, col="blue",pch=17,xlab="",ylab="")` Why is it placed on the first x value?

Comment: `plot(1)` then `plot(2, add = TRUE)`?

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but the codes below are for puting the plot2 value to the empty place...

I have just created a fake data since you haven't shared the entire one.

```
data <- 1:31
data[15]<-NA 

plot1 <- data 

plot2 <- 15

date <- as.character(1990:2020)

plot(date,plot1, col="red",pch=16,xlab = "Year", 
ylab = "Population",main = "Population of XXX from 1990 to 2020")
points("2004" ,plot2,col="blue")
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: It worked! I understand my problem now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `plot` the first time and then `points`

```
plot1 <- c(64123456,75123456,99417287) #total of 29 values
plot2 <- c(80824322)
plot(plot1, col="red",pch=16,xlab = "Year", ylab = "Population",main = "Population of XXX from 1990 to 2020",yaxt="n",xaxt="n",las=2)
points(plot2, col="blue",pch=17,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
```

Comment: I removed axes because it's giving an error. The code run but the 2nd data is placed on the first x value. The image is placed on the question as an update.

Comment: @Keeper: You have nothing that's tying your blue point to the correct x-axis value. Since you only have one value, it's associating it with the first x value by default. You need to do `points( xx, plot2, col="blue", ...)`, where `xx` is the x value that corresponds to 2004 (`xx = 15`, if I counted correctly).

Comment: I understand my mistake and it's working now. Thank you!